# Raspberry Pi Pico - Generate finite length square wave

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I have a question about generating square waves with finite length by using a Raspberry Pi Pico. For example, I want to generate a 20 kHz square wave with 100 periods, or to generate a 20 kHz square wave with an exact 1 ms. I cannot have accurate control over it.

To generate an infinite length of square waves is easy, as there are lots of examples online. I can use PIO to achieve it. For example, the following code could do so:

```
import rp2
from machine import Pin 
@rp2.asm_pio(set_init=rp2.PIO.OUT_LOW)
def blink():
    set(pins, 1)
    set(pins, 0)

sm = rp2.StateMachine(0, blink, freq=25000, set_base=Pin(26))

sm.active(1)
```

However, I don't know how to accurately control the length/periods of the square wave. By using time.sleep() is not accurate at all.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "decrement X" instruction in the PIO to count the number of cycles you want. Might have to add some delays to get back a square wave.  `jmp(x_dec, "top_of_loop")`.  You'd hang, waiting for some input, and read the X value from the input FIFO. Then you'd run the square-wave loop, decrementing X. When it hits zero, you jump to the outer loop, where you again wait for a new X value for the number of cycles. I think that's it!

Comment: Thank you! I got it.